# Using a variable in Date data type

Tags: vb.net

Currently I am looking at retrieving payments from a OLEDB Database, using quarters of the financial year.

The retrieval of the quarters works, but the part which doesnt is the year part. As shown below

```
Public Q1 As Date = Date.FromOADate(31 / 3 / 2014)
Public Q2 As Date = Date.FromOADate(30 / 6 / 2014)
Public Q3 As Date = Date.FromOADate(30 / 9 / 2014)
Public Q4 As Date = Date.FromOADate(31 / 12 / 2014)
```

Is what I currently use, but I would much rather the year to be a variable which can be retrieved from a combobox selection. Like so

```
Public Q1 As Date = Date.FromOADate(31 / 3 / Yearcombox.Text)
Public Q2 As Date = Date.FromOADate(30 / 6 / Yearcombox.Text)
Public Q3 As Date = Date.FromOADate(30 / 9 / Yearcombox.Text)
Public Q4 As Date = Date.FromOADate(31 / 12 / Yearcombox.Text)
```

Yet this does not work because of the data type 'Date' and presents a error which doesn't allow the form to load.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: FromOADate requires a double type as per MSDN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write This Way To Find Out The Date

you can convert the year to Double.

Follow This Code TOmSolve Your Problem.

> Date.FromOADate(30 / 3 / CDbl(Yearcombox.Text))

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of this!